# Add element(s) while creation into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a HashMap

```
myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> >();
```

I am writing a code where I want to add items in `ArrayList` for the key if it exists in the map,

```
myMap.get(key).add(element);
```

or else create a new `ArrayList`, add an item to the list, and add this list to the map.

```
ArrayList<String> tmpArrList = new ArrayList<>();
tmpArrList.add(element);
myMap.put(key, tmpArrayList);
```

Writing three lines for adding single element, do not look good to me, **how can I** **write it in single line using Java 5**.. ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, `computeIfAbsent` is what you need :

```
myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new).add(element);
```

This will generate a new `ArrayList` and put it in the `Map` if the requested key is not already present in the `Map`.

Comment: Great !, but unfortunately, I have to write something which supports Java 1.5 and above

Comment: @SimpleGuy I don't think there is a 1-liner solution prior to Java 8 (unless you use some external libraries).

Answer (score 1):

As you need a solution for **Java 5**, the best you could do is simplify this:

```
ArrayList<String> tmpArrList = new ArrayList<>();
tmpArrList.add(element);
myMap.put(key, tmpArrayList);
```

With this:

```
myMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singletonList(element)));
```

Or the code allowing to add an entry to your map could be:

```
if (!myMap.containsKey(key)) {
    myMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
}
myMap.get(key).add(element);
```

You could also consider using a [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [**Google Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava) but note that it is only stating from **Java 6** for the most recent versions hopefully there are existing backports for **Java 5** of the versions `13.0`, `14.0`, `16.0` and `17.0` available from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5), more details [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Compatibility).

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> myMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
// This will map the provided key with the provided value whetever the
// total amount of values already mapped with this key  
myMap.put(key, element);
```

Comment: According to Guava's [Release History](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory): *Releases 1.0 through 11.0 require JDK 1.5 or newer. Releases 12.0 through 20.0 require JDK 1.6 or newer*. Since [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) was adding in 2.0, using version 11.0 should do it.

Comment: @Andreas the link that I provide, propose a backport of `13.0`, `14.0`, `16.0` and  `17.0` which is even better

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write it in single line.. ? *(from question)*
>   I have to write something which supports Java 1.5 and above *(from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884393/add-elements-while-creation-into-arraylist#comment68982982_40884457))*

You can't. The shortest way to write it is:

```
ArrayList<String> list = myMap.get(key);
if (list == null)
    myMap.put(key, list = new ArrayList<String>());
list.add(element);
```

This is optimized to only perform one map lookup, unlike an implementation using `containsKey()` to detect if a new `ArrayList` is needed.

Except:

1. Just write it all on a single line<sup>*</sup>:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> list = myMap.get(key); if (list == null) myMap.put(key, list = new ArrayList<String>()); list.add(element);
   ```

   <sup>* Yes, that's a joke, though technically a valid answer to the question.</sup>
2. Create a helper method, e.g. in a shared utility class:

   ```
   public static <K, V> void addToMapList(Map<K, ArrayList<V>> mapList, K key, V value) {
       ArrayList<V> list = mapList.get(key);
       if (list == null)
           mapList.put(key, list = new ArrayList<V>());
       list.add(value);
   }
   ```

   Then using it is a single line:

   ```
   MyUtil.addToMapList(myMap, key, element);
   ```
3. Use [Apache Commons Collections ™](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)<sup>*</sup> class [`MultiValueMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html):

   ```
   MultiMap<String, String> myMap = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();

   myMap.put(key, element);
   ```

   <sup>* For Java 5, use version 4.0.</sup>
4. Use [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki)<sup>*</sup> class [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html):

   ```
   ListMultimap<String, String> myMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   myMap.put(key, element);
   ```

   <sup>* For Java 5, use [version 11.0](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory).</sup>
5. Write your own `MultiMap`.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to go with multiple lines..... as I cant change the Map to something else like `ListMultimap`